# Algorithm visualization for C#

Tags: c#, visualization, code-visualization

Is there any software that visualizes algorithms from code? As a flow chart of something similar. Not dependencies, inheritance and that kind of thing, but the code inside a function, or a series of functions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question,  While it does provide some valuable insite to the community. It's a clear violation of our guidelines (Software Recomendations, and could potentially cause issues, because it could be seen as an audit in the review queue)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know about *inside* a function, but VS2010 has sequence diagram generation from code - see  [here](http://dotnet.org.za/willy/archive/2008/11/18/visual-studio-2010-ctp-2-a-close-encounter-with-sequence-diagram.aspx) or [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jasonz/archive/2009/05/18/announcing-vs2010-net-framework-4-0-beta-1.aspx)

[image: Sequence diagram]

Answer (score 3):

I think you may be looking for [Code Rocket](http://www.getcoderocket.com).

It provides flowchart and pseudocode visualizations of code methods and algorithms, embedded directly inside Visual Studio and Eclipse - and there is a separate Designer application for working outwith IDEs too.

Answer (score 2):

[AiVosto](http://www.aivosto.com/) has a set of tools to visualize source code from many languages: Visustin. It is on the market since a long time. I tried it a very long time ago, was not 100% convinved. Maybe you want to give it a try and evaluate if it's worth the money for you.

For me it was so that in order to understand some complex algorithm, I have anyway to experiment with it, having a graph helps a bit but as a coder you probably can visualize loops and decision trees well without software. I don't want to discourage you from using that, just try it out before investing money, having graphs is nice but shall also be useful.